# How to obtain application base url in Exception filter scope?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have app being hosted at url

`https://example.com/app/____`

Now I have custom `ExceptionFilter` which is responsible for redirect after exception

```
public class CustomExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var ex = context.Exception;
        var c = (ControllerActionDescriptor)context.ActionDescriptor;

        (...)
        context.Result = new RedirectResult("/Error");
    }
}
```

the problem is that it redirects to

`https://example.com/Error/`

but I need to redirect it to `/app/Error`, so I need to obtain that `base path` which is `/app/`

I tried

> context.Result = new RedirectResult("Error");
>
> context.Result = new RedirectResult("./Error");

but they're being added at the end, so it looks like

`https://example.com/app/auth/Error`

meanwhile my goal is

`https://example.com/app/Error`

So, how can I obtain app `path base` in `exception filter`?

Comment: so you have the basepath but only need the first part of it? you could subtract url, then split by '/' and take first element?

Comment: `so you have the basepath` I would have to hard code it, but is possible to extract it from framework or something?

Comment: via `HttpContext.Current.Request` no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accessing base path, you could try `context.HttpContext.Request.PathBase.Value`.

```
public class CustomExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var basePath = context.HttpContext.Request.PathBase.Value;
        context.Result = new RedirectResult($"{ basePath }/Error");
    }
}
```